# System.TypeLoadException C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm student. I'm finishing my graduation work. So I have been doing my app for 6 months on Xamarin Forms, and in one moment my InitializeComponent() crashed. I tried to fix it, but I couldn't. Please can you help me in my stupid situation. Really it is very stupid, because I didn't do any backup copy!!!!!!!

[image]

I have cleared, built, rebuilt my solution. It didn't help. Clear all bin and obj repositories, and it also didn't help me. I'm confused and lost guesses what should I do!

Comment: do you have anything in your App.xaml file?

Comment: Do you have different versions of the Xamarin.Forms nuget packages in your solution? Please check it, Then update all of your nuget packages to the latest.

Comment: Thx, it's really helped me

Comment: Do you solve this issue by updating your nuget packages to same version and latest?